Window.scrollTo not working in nextjs scrolling to an ID feature
I'm using the scroll to an ID feature from next.js. What I'm trying to do is when I click on a link the section should take a margin from the top.
As per the below code, I'm getting all the values in console logs and there are no errors in console as well.
But when I click on the link to jump to a particular section. The window.scrollTo is not working.
I'm trying to apply the same scroll-margin-top CSS through JavaScript.

'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function Scroll() {
    const refs = Array.from({ length: 8 }, () => React.createRef());

    const handleClick = index => {
        const ref = refs[index];
        if (ref.current) {
            console.log(ref.current)
            const distanceToTop = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            console.log("distanceToTop", distanceToTop);
            const margin = 20;
            const headerHeight = document.getElementById('navHeader').offsetHeight; // Get header height
            console.log("headerHeight", headerHeight);
            const scrollPosition = distanceToTop - headerHeight - margin; // Subtract header height
            console.log("scrollPosition", scrollPosition);
            try {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: headerHeight,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                });
                console.log("scroll")
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error scrolling:", error);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex w-screen" id="section">
                <section className="sidebar max-w-md w-full relative">
                    <ul className={`flex flex-col items-center p-7 `}>
                        {refs.map((ref, index) => (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <Link href={`#${index + 1}`}>
                                    <button onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>My {index + 1} section</button>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section className="content flex flex-col w-full " id="section" >
                    {refs.map((ref, index) => (
                        <div ref={ref} id={`${index + 1}`} className={`bg-slate-600 h-52 `} key={index}>SECTION {index + 1}</div>
                    ))}
                </section>
            </div>
            <div>
                <footer className="h-96 bg-fuchsia-200">
                    footer
                </footer>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}


Please check below sandbox link
Demo

Can you provide the link to a sandbox that replicated this error?

Sure. I have added the link below the code. Please check.
